# Change target sdk on Phonegap for nodejs

Tags: node.js, cordova, android-sdk-tools

Im using phonegap on nodejs, but when I use the command

```
phonegap local build android
```

It automatically ask me for "Android 4.2 SDK"

> Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK). Make sure you
>   have the latest Android tools installed as well.

How can I choose a lower vesion (android 4.1) of the sdk using phonegap for nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't have to!

I struggled with this until I installed v17 and completed my first build. It [turns out](http://softwaregosh.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/compiling-phonegap-hello-world-to.html) that the generated Androidmanifest.xml has minSdkVersion=10, so the minimum version required for your application is 2.3.3, it just needs to compile against v17.